# MailItem.IsConflict vs Conflicts Object

Tags: vba, object, outlook, conflict, mailitem

I am trying to check if a mailitem is in conflict.

I haven't run these yet, but are they equivalent codes, or is there a difference?

```
Sub CheckConflict1()
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Dim myConflicts As Outlook.Conflicts
    Set myConflicts = myItem.Conflicts

    If (myConflicts.Count > 0) Then
        MsgBox ("This item is involved in a conflict.")
    Else
        MsgBox ("This item is not involved in any conflicts.")
    End If
End Sub


Sub CheckConflict2()
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    If (myItem.IsConflict = False) Then
        MsgBox ("This item is involved in a conflict.")
    Else
        MsgBox ("This item is not involved in any conflicts.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched these links and noticed that it seems both the functions are different.

[Conflicts Object (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.conflicts)

[MailItem.IsConflict Property (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.isconflict)

For the "Conflicts Object", it determine if the item is involved in any conflict.

For the "IsConflict", it determined by the state of the application.

Anyway, I think you need to run the code as above links.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't see a visible difference. Running both the codes seem to give me identical results, especially when checking if a mailitem is in a state of conflict, whatever the conflict may be. Maybe the latter suffices for detecting first-hand conflicts. I should test it further to be sure.